# very important interface

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, contract-debugging

I have a problem, can anyone help me?
I want to change the value in another contract
another contract name Token
i want change example balances[msg.sender] = 0;

this a code

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

interface Tokens {
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;
}

contract Tokenn {
    uint public exportsbalance;

    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) public allowance;

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);

    function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns (uint) {
        return owner.balance;
    }
    
    function setTransfer(address _counter, address from, uint value) public {
        exportsbalance = Tokens(_counter).balances();
        exportsbalance[msg.sender] -= value;
        exportsbalance[from] += value;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, from, value);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to acheive here. This interface `interface Tokens { mapping(address => uint) public balances; }` can never write balance, this is just for querying balances of a given address.

Comment: i want write the balance from another contract my brother wallet he forget the password and i want to return the balance to me agin

Comment: If he has forgotten the password then the funds are likely lost. You can't just re-assign them like you've suggested. Otherwise anyone would be able to send funds from an address they didn't own.